# How to treat all Service Reference return types the same

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, service-reference

I have a Silverlight project which references a handful of web services. Each web service method returns a standard response wrapper object called `GenericWebResponse`. This class contains information about whether or no the call was successful, and some status codes if it failed to indicate why it failed. Common things are that the authentication ticket expired, or the user doesn't have permission to perform the action.

Anyway, whenever a web service call fails, I want to treat it the same way. I want to create a log entry, notify the user something went wrong, etc.

Since I have multiple services, each service reference generates a new instance of the same `GenericWebResponse` class. So I have `ProductService.GenericWebResponse` and `OrderService.GenericWebResponse`, and obviously .NET treats them as entirely separate classes.

I want a way to write code against these objects generically. I know that the response will always be the same, but .NET doesn't know that. I get that. But is there some way I can write code against these objects so that I don't have to write an new version of my failure logging code for each service I have?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a partial class for each proxy generated response type, which implements a common interface that you define, and in your implementation you forward to the concrete proxy generated type. With T4, there might be a way to get that autogenerated rather than do it by hand.

If you defined the services and have access to the Interface types then, then you could create the proxies in a different way....either a dynamic proxy....or use your own T4 template.

http://wcfdynamicclient.codeplex.com/

http://intellecting.net/blog/post/Using-T4-To-Generate-WCF-Client-Proxy.aspx

Have used DynamicProxy in the past...has 2 benefits....it solves the niggle of when the channel faults you can't use the proxy any more....and also while developing in which your Service interface is fluid/evolving....you don't have to keep updating your Service Reference each time....using the C# Interface of your Service means you stay in sync when you build.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the fields will be exactly the same, one option would be to use reflection to extract the property values.

Answer (score 0):

If the services are .NET services, then when you use "Add Service Reference", you can click "Advanced", and choose "Reuse types". You will need to reference the project containing the original types, but it should use the real type for each reference.